# Complex potentials in plane polar coordinates - stream function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

Determine the stream function and the potential in plane polar coordinates and sketching streamlines.

We need to take the value of m=1.
I know how to find the stream function and velocity potential, but I'm unsure on how the diagram is meant to look and how to follow through with the whole qustion after part 1. Can anyone give me a pointer?

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to express $z=x+iy$ in polar coordinates? Do you know how to get $\vec{u}(r,\theta)$ from $\psi$ and/or $\phi$? If there is a solid object, what would you expect $\vec{u}$ to look like in and around that object?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow#Analysis_for_two-dimensional_flow) may be of help to you, as well as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).